FireAllClients event seems to be firing a random number of times whenever ran
I have a script located in a tool that activates upon the tool's activation (when you left-click with the tool in hand). When activated, a RemoveEvent fires on all clients. Here's that code:
local tool = script.Parent

local debounce = false
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    if debounce == false then
        debounce = true
        local player = game:GetService"Players":GetPlayerFromCharacter(script.Parent.Parent)
        local character = script.Parent.Parent
        
        local foodvalue = 5
        player.PlayerGui.Meters.AteFoodEvent:FireAllClients(player,foodvalue)
        print(foodvalue)
        wait(2)
    end
    debounce = false
end)

(The wait(2) and debounce is just to try to solve this problem, which has not worked)
This seems to work just fine and the print function only prints one "foodvalue", being five. But, when I look at the script that recieves the RemoteEvent...
player.PlayerGui.Meters.AteFoodEvent.OnClientEvent:Once(function(player,foodvalue)

    if eventDebounce == false then
        eventDebounce = true
        if hunger > foodvalue then
            hunger -= foodvalue
        elseif hunger <= foodvalue then
            hunger = -1
            print(foodvalue)
        end
        wait(2)
    end
    eventDebounce = false
end)

No matter where I print the foodvalue, or wait(2), or debounce, the amount of "foodvalues" that get printed out ranges from one to fifteen, seemingly with no correlation to anything other than the hunger value, but even then the only relation is that when the hunger value is low the printed foodvalue is usually lower, and same with a higher hunger value. I have no clue what's going on!

The fact that you are using OnClientEvent:Once should ensure that the event triggers once, and never again. So since you see a bunch of logs for something that should happen once, a good place to look is whether you might have multiple scripts all connecting to the same event, or clones of this script somewhere. The next time you test and you see a bunch of messages, go into the Explorer widget, and search for the name of the LocalScript, and see if there are multiple copies for some reason.
